# Withdrawal process

Tags: withdrawal

My broker asked Me to pay verification fee which is $670 and provide my  ID I wanna ask is it legit to do that ? I invested 350 and earned $12000k

Comment: This sounds like a scam

Comment: How precisely do you know that you earned that amount? Be as precise as you can. Did you independently confirm that your trades were profitable? Are you taking the broker's word for it?

Answer (score 3):

Who said you earned 12000k from 350 ? if it is just written on a website maybe it is fake, also there is no need for verification fee and ID in the bitcoin network, if you send him coins using bitcoin, you no longer own them, and there is no support service to retrieve them for you, be careful of scam.